# Pandas version discrepancy, pd.concat(sort=False)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I've written some code for someone else.

At a certain point in the code, I use:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=False)
```

However the person who is actually running the code is using an older version of Pandas which is not compatible with the 'sort' parameter. They also do not have admin rights and so cannot update the version of Pandas (20.0.1) that they are using.

How can I resolve this? Is there a workaround in the code which would prevent his concat function from automatically ordering the columns alphabetically despite not having the later version of Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the dataframes and then rearrange the columns afterwards:

```py
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
print(
    new_df[df1.columns.tolist() + df2.columns.tolist() + df3.columns.tolist()]
)
```

---

EDIT: To filter out duplicated columns (when some overlap):

```py
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

out, seen = [], set()
for c in df1.columns.tolist() + df2.columns.tolist() + df3.columns.tolist():
    if c not in seen:
        out.append(c)
        seen.add(c)

print(new_df[out])
```

Comment: Good idea!  +1   but what if the dataframes have overlapping columns ?  I'm not sure actually.  Just thinking about it.  Maybe it's fine.

Comment: The columns do indeed overlap. It's actually time series data, the first 5 or so columns of each data frame are fixed and identical but then the point of the concat is then to stack the time series data in the correct location.

Comment: @SeaBean Yeah, then there will be duplicated columns. I update the answer to remove the duplicities.

Comment: @AndrejKesely  I'm also testing on this to see how it goes.  Great work for the update!  :-)

Comment: As far as I can tell this has worked! I will leave the question open just until tomorrow when I've had time to fully scope the result. Thank you